# database [table name DATA_PES]

Tags: perl, scripting

```
my @DATA_PES = ( 
     { col_name=>"rpad(request_no,9) as request_number",col_width=>9,col_mandatory_yn=>"n" }
```

what does this mean

Answer (score 4):

On tidying up, the code becomes:

```
my @DATA_PES = (
    {
        'col_name'         => 'rpad(request_no,9) as request_number',
        'col_width'        => 9,
        'col_mandatory_yn' => 'n',
    }
);
```

- `@DATA_PES` is an array which contains a single element.
- This single element is a hash reference.
- The hash reference contains three pairs of keys and values.

See also:

- [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) - Perl data types
- [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) - Perl Data Structures Cookbook